# How to create array of (pointers to arrays of various lenth) and pass it from cython to python

Tags: arrays, cython

I would like to create an array of pointers in cython. Each pointer should point to an array of varying size. And finally the structure should return to python. Is that possible or I am missing something? Not working code is posted bellow, but it may be question of proper definitions. It refuses to compile with the message: "Buffers with pointer types not yet supported".

Any help is appreciated!

```
# cython: language_level=3
from cpython cimport array as arr

def mainFunc():
    ArrayOfPointers = ArrayOfPointersGenerator("path")
    print(ArrayOfPointers[0][1]) ## 12
    print(ArrayOfPointers[1][2]) ## 23
    return 0

def ArrayOfPointersGenerator(path):
    cdef arr.array[unsigned int] Message1, Message2
    cdef unsigned int *PonterToMessage1, *PonterToMessage2
    cdef arr.array[unsigned int *] ArrayOfPointersToArrays

    Message1 = arr.clone(arr.array('I'), 2, False)
    Message1[0]=11
    Message1[1]=12

    Message2 = arr.clone(arr.array('I'), 3, False)
    Message2[0]=21
    Message2[1]=22
    Message2[2]=23

    PonterToMessage1 = <unsigned int*>Message1[0]
    PonterToMessage2 = <unsigned int*>Message2[0]

    ArrayOfPointersToArrays = arr.clone(arr.array('I'), 2, False)

    ArrayOfPointersToArrays[0]=PonterToMessage1
    ArrayOfPointersToArrays[1]=PonterToMessage2

    return ArrayOfPointersToArrays
```

Comment: At the Python level, you are talking about either a list of lists, or a numpy array with object dtype.  In a numpy case that's a fall-back choice, something that's used when an regular array can't be created.  Performance wise it is inferior to both the multidimensional array and the list.

Comment: What do you actually want to do with it in Python (given that Python doesn't really have the concept of pointers)? If you just want to pass it around then an opaque cdef class might be the best thing. If you really want to access it as a Numpy array (but to do *what*?) then maybe `intptr_t` would work?

Comment: The potential object is humongous, so the space saving of the arrays over lists of lists is something to consider. Pointer arithmetic is also faster than indexing, especially if these are c arrays. I do not necessary need to go pack to python. What should be the type of pointers in use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to bear in mind: if your code had compiled then it would have been a memory management disaster. As soon as you start to use pointers you are taking responsibility for ensuring that they point somewhere valid, and Cython can't handle that for you.

In this case

```
PonterToMessage1 = <unsigned int*>&Message1[0]
PonterToMessage2 = <unsigned int*>&Message2[0]
```

are intended to point to data inside `Message1` and `Message2` (note that I've added a `&` which wasn't present in your code though...). However `Message1` and `Message2` have nothing to link their lifetime to that of `ArrayOfPointersToArrays` and thus are probably deallocated at the end of the function.

If you are not confident with this idea then I suggest not using pointers at all.

---

With that in mind:

- The simplest solution is probably a list of numpy arrays (*not* a list of lists). That way you still get the benefits of the data being efficiently packed in the arrays, but you also get the memory managed for free and the ability to access things in Python.
- If you just want to pass this big block of data around through Python (and not access it) you could write a cdef class to wrap some C allocated pointers

  ```
  # note - untested code
  cdef class RaggedArrayWrapper:
      cdef int** data
      cdef int length
      def __cinit__(self, lengths: list):
           self.data = malloc(sizeof(int*)*len(lengths))
           self.length = len(lengths)
           for n, l in enumerate(lengths):
               self.data[n] = malloc(sizeof(int)*l)
      def __dealloc__(self):
          for i in range(self.length):
              free(self.data[n])
          free(self.data)
  ```

  The disadvantage of this approach is that you are responsible for your own memory management and keeping track of the bounds. But it isn't too hard to wrap them all in a constructor/destructor
- Finally, you could use a Numpy array filled with `uintptr_t` (this has the Numpy dtype `np.uintp`). This is an unsigned integer large enough to hold a pointer. You'll need to cast your pointers to this integer type. If you choose to do this you are responsible for your own memory.

Comment: Very pedagogical and nice answer, thank you very much! As for the ampersand, I realized my mistake quite quickly after I posted. However, the wrapper class is a charm, thanks.